# Use OneHotEncoder inverse_transform

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pip

I want to use `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` to transform but then also inverse transform. The latest version os `sklearn` I can download via pip is `0.19.0` (`pip2 install upgrade sklearn`)but the feature is only added in a later version.

How can I either upgrade to the latest sklearn, or use inverse transform on `0.19.0`?

I use `python2`

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.inverse_transform

Comment: The package is named `scikit-learn`. `pip2 install --upgrade scikit-learn`

Comment: it worked! Strangely with `sklearn` the pip installation alsow orks but not the latest version

Comment: `sklearn` is just a placeholder that points to `scikit-learn` in the description. Although it can be installed via `pip`, it doesn't contain any code at all.

Comment: yes, but not the latest version